# Git does not work when Jenkins Slave is running as Windows Service

Tags: git, jenkins

If we run the Jenkins Slave as a Windows Service git fails to to fetch with the error

```
The server's host key is not cached in the registry
```

The service is running as a specific domain user which we have set up using putty. If we log into the machine with that user Git Bash works without requesting a password so the SSH key is set up correctly.

We discovered that if you use the Command line to start the Jenkins Slave under the User we set the ssh key up as the build works. The command we use is

```
javaws http://brick:8083/computer/nsw-buildbox1/slave-agent.jnlp
```

This works perfectly fine. I suspect that despite the fact the service is still running as the same domain user there is something different where it can't find the .ssh folder. Has anyone run into this issue and know of a way to fix it. Where does a windows service look for the known hosts?

Even know we have a workaround it means if you restart the machine the build will not work until you login and run the startup command

Answer (score 2):

I know this might be late to answer this question, but this is the root cause for your problem.

- When you running slave by:
  **javaws http://brick:8083/computer/nsw-buildbox1/slave-agent.jnlp**
  you are actually running the slave as current logged user, the system already have your ssh session cached for current user correctly.
- But when you selected to install it as an service,your Windows service is not actually running as current user. that why you are always given this error "The server's host key is not cached in the registry". Yes, you have never connected to the server as the service's user.
  To fix it, you must manually make the service running as current user.Do

  1. Run 'services.msc'
  2. Locate 'Jenkins Slave' service
  3. Property-> Log on-> Choose your current user.

Answer (score 0):

This is not the `.ssh` folder, but the registry.

[Mount the registry hive of that user](http://www.osattack.com/walk-through/tutorial-how-to-mount-a-registry-hive/), and search under `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\SimonTatham\Putty\SshHostKeys`. Copy your host key there, it should contain the host key.

Comment: On the user we have the service running as it already has an entry under that path. Does running a Windows Service as a specific user (not Local System or Network User) have a different hive that if you actually login using that user? if so where is it located

Comment: Each user have its own registry hive. It's in the user's profile. The infamous `USER.DAT` file.

Comment: Ok so if you have a user called Bob and under the service you set it to start using Bob instead of Local System, wouldn't it use the same User.Dat in C:\users\Bob\NTUSER.Dat (i assume its the NTUSER.Dat for Win7). This can't be the case because it works when we run it from command line for that user. so what .dat file would a windows service use?

Comment: I think i might have answered that question. looks like a service does not load HKEY_CURRENT_USER. http://serverfault.com/questions/311976/registry-keys-unavailable-to-application-being-run-from-a-service will plink work if we add it to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\SimonTatham\Putty\SshHostKeys

Comment: I guess it is easier to use ssh in git for windows instead of plink

Comment: can you give me some pointers on getting this to work with jenkins?